# How to get my Web Service response XML to validate in Liquid XML Studio?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, xsd

Web Service code (ASP.NET 2.0):

```
[WebMethod]
[return: XmlElement("TestMe")]
public string TestMe(int value)
{
  return value.ToString();
}
```

The will result in this response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <TestMeResponse xmlns="http://example.org/WebServiceTest">
      <TestMe>7499</TestMe>
    </TestMeResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

If I save this as a XML file, open it up in [Liquid XML Studio](http://www.liquid-technologies.com) and try to validate it, I get this error message:

```
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://example.org/WebServiceTest:TestMeResponse'.
Could not find schema information for the element 'http://example.org/WebServiceTest:TestMe'
```

So how do I add the correct namespace and/or schema for this to validate correctly?

My WSDL ...asmx?WSDL includes the schema definition for the TestMeResponse and TestMe elements, but how do I get this into the response?

Answer (score 1):

You don't put the schema in the response. It's in the WSDL. You'll need to pull the schema (or schemas) out of the WSDL for Liquid XML to see.